# changing ReSharper Template for IEquatable and IEqualityComparer

Tags: c#, resharper, iequalitycomparer, iequatable

Is there a way to change the implementation details, when you add a `IEquatable<T>` or `IEqualityComparer<T>` with ReSharper to your own class?
I am using R# Ultimate 2016.3

I want to have some brackets around single if statement, because of StyleCop Rules.
And also want to use C#6 Features like null-coalescing in the `GetHashcode` method, for example, so that i don't have to change that every time by hand.

edit 09.01.2017

[Same question in R# Community](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000018690-changing-Template-for-IEquatable-and-IEqualityComparer-in-2016-3)